# CSS Grid layout with equal width sections columns and sections with borders/margins

Tags: html, css, css-grid, subgrid

I am looking to have a grid layout (3 columns) of repeating sections. I want the sections to have border and margins as well as have equal width columns throughout all sections. I have gotten most of the way there but am battling between no border/margin using display: contents; or unequal widths. Is what I am asking for css subgrid? (poorly supported), is there another way or am I left to apply border/margin to children?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.sectionWrap {
  display: contents;
  border: 3px solid purple;
  margin: 6px;
}

.c1,
.c2,
.c3 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sectionWrap">
    <div class="c1">
      shorter text
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionWrap">
    <div class="c1">
      longer text...............
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span> unfortunately missing my border and margin using display: contents.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Margin can be replaced with gap and border with individual border on your elements:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  row-gap:12px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.sectionWrap {
  display: contents;
}


.c1 {
  border:3px solid purple;
  border-right:1px solid blue;
}
.c2 {
  border:3px solid purple;
  border-right:1px solid blue;
  border-left:1px solid blue;
}
.c3 {
  border:3px solid purple;
  border-left:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sectionWrap">
    <div class="c1">
      shorter text
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionWrap">
    <div class="c1">
      longer text...............
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span>
```

Comment: thank you, had not though about grid gap in that way, but makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all of your columns the same width by changing `grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;` to `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;`  This is how your code looks with this change and I also removed the `display: contents;`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.sectionWrap {
  border: 3px solid purple;
  margin: 6px;
}

.c1,
.c2,
.c3 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sectionWrap">
    <div class="c1">
      shorter text
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionWrap">
    <div class="c1">
      longer text...............
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span> unfortunately missing my border and margin using display: contents.
```

Comment: thx for reply, but this changes the layout, looking for it to look like mine just with border/margin.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure on that as you said simply adding `display:contents;` changed the width.  Please look at Temani Afif's answer then. I believe it is what you want. Also FYI, you can use my `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;` change in conjunction with his code and it will make all your width's the same.